# URL Rewrite - remove ?url=

Tags: url-rewriting

I have an address which is `/blog?url=article-1`

Is there a way to just remove the `?url=` part and replace it with a forward slash?

So, in the end, the URL should look like `/blog/article-1`

I have tried many htaccess routes and none seem to work.

I am using Windows and I am building a simple blog.

The URL works and everything but I just need it to look like `/blog/article-1` instead of `/blog?url=article-1`.

What I have mainly tried when searching on Stack Overflow is this code:

```
RewriteRule ^edit/id/([0-9]+)/?$ edit.php?id=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Changed the values in it with no luck, what would I change the above code to? Or is the above code entirely wrong for what I need?

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: I have done this with IIS but what are you using linux, windows? and I think this question belongs to stackoverflow not here

Answer (score 1):

> The URL works and everything but I just need it to look like `/blog/article-1` instead of `/blog?url=article-1`

This should be done in your web application, not .htaccess. It is a common mistake (at least a common question) to attempt to do this part in .htaccess, as it will result in multiple external redirects on every request - which is not desirable.

The only time you do this in .htaccess is when you need to correct old URLs that have been indexed and linked to. Essentially a canonical redirect.

> `RewriteRule ^edit/id/([0-9]+)/?$ edit.php?id=$1 [NC,QSA,L]`

What you should then use .htaccess for is to *internally rewrite* the virtual (pretty) URL to the real URL. That is what this directive is doing.

So, the basic process is:

1. User clicks on "virtual" link (a URL) on your website: `/blog/article-1`
2. Directive in .htaccess internally rewrites the request to the real file that handles the request: `/blog.php?url=article-1`. (Although the file extension is missing on the URLs in your question.) Since this is an *internal rewrite* (as opposed to an *external redirect*) the URL in the address bar does not change.